# Why won't source function work in R Markdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio

More of a conceptual question than a strictly coding one. I have an .R script dedicated to importing and generally cleaning my data. I have several different .Rmd scripts that use the data from the general cleaning .R script to run their specific analyses. I would like to be able to `source("DataCleaning.R")` at the beginning of each of the .Rmd scripts, that way I could reduce redundancy, but I'm getting this error:

```
'Pulling' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I could fix this problem by exporting and importing a .csv, but I'm kind of confused why `source()` won't work. I've tried it on a few computers now. Works fine in .R but not .Rmd. Would have sworn I've used it in .Rmd in the past. I reread the documentation on it. I couldn't find anyone else reporting this exact error message, but I'm trying to find the file containing the code to take a closer look at 'Pulling'.

#### QUESTION:

Does source not work in .Rmd, or is this a unique case?

#### UPDATE:

I managed to get the problem to go away by uninstalling both R and R Studio and reinstalling them. Updating them did not work. The code for `source` looked fine to me. Still scratching my head a little at this one, because it worked in a regular R script but not R markdown, and was giving me an issue across two different machines, both of which were resolved when I did the full reinstall. I suppose it's fixed for now, but not sure what it could have been.

This question was closed for nonspecificity and not providing reproducible code, but, again, those standards can't really apply in this case because it was a machine-specific problem. I just needed to know whether I was misunderstanding the role of the function. Hopefully the update addresses the critiques, but obviously feel free to close it again if not.

Comment: I think we would need to know what the contents of DataCleaning.R are

Comment: It's very possible that this was in fact machine-specific, but there was no way for anybody else to know that. Those sorts of questions are definitely hard to diagnose. I'd vote to reopen if you included details on the machines where it did & didn't work (like `sessionInfo` calls) so people had something more to go on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes `source` does work in .Rmd.  Here's a reproducible example to prove it:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
fname = tempfile()
writeLines('print("hello")', fname)
```

```{r}
source(fname)
```
````

[image]

The error you are getting must be caused by the content of your external file.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. Unfortunately, I'm getting this error no matter what .R file I'm sourcing (including your example), so I think I must have a corrupted file or error somewhere. Still very helpful to know. Thanks for your time!

Comment: If you can't fix it yourself (e.g. by reinstalling packages or R or RStudio) then you should add some more information to help diagnose the problem. A reproducible example of both your source file and a minimal Rmd that gives the error will be needed.  Also version numbers for R and packages.  OS and platform (if Rstudio, then which version).

Comment: Another thought - is it possible that you have overwritten the `source` function with another function of the same name.   Please also check this.